# ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'Management' when create task using schtasks on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, windows-task-scheduler

I am using following command to create a task in task scheduler on Windows Server 2019. It works fine.

But when I try to run the same command in Docker then it throws error. I am using this command in `Dockerfile` so build image always fails due to it.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
RUN mkdir /StudentManagementSystemConsole
COPY ./Release /StudentManagementSystemConsole
RUN schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "Student Management System" /tr "C:\StudentManagementSystemConsole\StudentManagementSystemConsole.exe"
```

Error I am getting is:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'Management'.
Type "SCHTASKS /CREATE /?" for usage.
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Escape *Quotation Mark*s as `/tn \"Student Management System\"`?

Comment: Tried this and now I am getting a different error `ERROR: The task XML contains a value which is incorrectly formatted or out of range.`